# фоновая картинка пропадает при рендере анимации

Tags: анимация, 2d, blender

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы при рендере анимации не пропадала фоновая картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть небольшой проект, в качестве фона добавлена картинка поверх которой на другом слое создана анимация
после этого я хочу отренедерить эту анимацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в итоге все ренедерится без фона и финальное видео просто на белом фоне отрабатывает анимация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне это устранить и сделать так, чтобы фон тоже рендерился

Answer (score 1):

У вас картинка добавлена через референс. Они предназначены для референсов или чертежей, но не для рендера. Чтобы добавить картинку, которую можно рендерить, включите в настройках аддон Import Images as Planes
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем File -> Import -> Images as Planes

Выберите вашу картинку и нажмите Shadless (чтобы избежать теней на картинке) в настройках материала сбоку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]